# Не работает библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В чём проблема?
Не работает [image: Код]

Единственное предположение, что из-за того, что телеграм заблокирован в России

Comment: Если дело в блокировке, посоветуйте нетребовательный впн

Comment: Скрипт не смог подключиться к API. Думаю, причина в блокировке. Кст, код и текст ошибок не стоит оформлять скриншотами, лучше и код, текст ошибки разместить как текст

Answer (score 0):

Так и есть. Либо качай VPN, либо через GitHub и Heroku делай.

Comment: Могу посоветовать хороший бесплатный VPN. BroVPN называется. Там 4Мб/с бесплатно.